# 3-5v micro stepper connected to A4988 driver does not move and makes whirring noise

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, stepper

I am kind of a newbie when it comes to stepper motors so I am hoping I am not asking any stupid questions.

I am trying to run a 3-5v micro stepper motor ([PM15S-020-SKH4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CE79FGG)) using a [Pololu A4988](https://www.pololu.com/product/1182) stepper driver. I know the driver isn't originally meant for low-voltage stepper motors but I had some lying around and from what I understand it should not be a problem as long as the pot-value is set correctly.

Now I've identified the coils on the stepper motor and connected everything with an 12V power supply, Arduino Uno, `100uF` capacitor as described in the [Pololu](https://www.pololu.com/product/1182) schematic. I couldn't find the current specification for the stepper motor but if my calculations are correct with `5V / 30 Ohm` it should be `160 mAmp` so per another calculation I've set vRef value for the pot-meter to `0.160 * 0.4 = 0,064`

The code I run on the Arduino is;

```
#define PIN_DIR 1
#define PIN_STEP 3
#define PIN_ENABLE 5

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(PIN_DIR, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(PIN_STEP, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PIN_ENABLE, OUTPUT); 

    digitalWrite(PIN_ENABLE,LOW);
}

void loop() 
{
    digitalWrite(PIN_DIR,HIGH); 

    // 20 pulses of 18 degrees should make one full rotation
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        digitalWrite(PIN_STEP,HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(500);

        digitalWrite(PIN_STEP,LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(500);
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

When running the above code, the shaft is harder to move compared to a disconnected motor so there is resistance between the coils what should indicated that they are powered. But when running this the only thing the motor does is make a whirring noise and struggle/tick when I try to rotate it with my fingers.

I have tried multiple of the same type motors and drivers but all yield the same result.

I have a feeling I am overlooking something very obvious but I have no idea what, or am I being a complete idiot trying to combine the Pololu A4988 and the PM15S-020-SKH4?

Comment: Maybe your current is *too* low?

Comment: I have tried to increase the vRef on the pot-meter in ranges from 0.1 until even 1 (where to motor got really hot) but all with the same result.

Comment: Any chance you mixed up the pins and are toggle the direction or enable but not the step?  Are both coils truly connected?

Comment: I have given up on trying to get this to work and switched to a servo. I have hooked up the setup to a NEMA17 stepper motor (with alterations to the current) and it works fine. I have tried the small stepper motor in many, if not all configurations and I just can't get them to work.